# I am currently stuck in creating a bidirectional connection between Jitsu and Ecwid. Has anyone experienced something similar?

Tags: pipeline, webhooks, web-development-server, lightspeed

I conducted some research on Jitsu API and how it can be used to integrate with other APIs. My issue is that I have no knowledge of how to connect Jitsu with Ecwid as Ecwid also does not support integration with Jitsu. I am curious to know if there are ways to connect the two together bidirectionally with webhooks. If not, please let me know any custom solutions that may work or have worked to connect Jitsu and Ecwid together.

I did research on Jitsu event APIs but got no insight on how to connect Jitsu to Ecwid. As a result, I have not been able to produce any results positive or negative to create the connection.

Answer (score -1):

Walter here, Ecwid by Lightspeed API team.

We have an open API you can use and it supports webhooks for such integrations: https://api-docs.ecwid.com/reference/overview

Let me help you with getting started. First, you need to have an Ecwid store and a custom application in that store. To get a custom application, just visit this page: https://my.ecwid.com/#develop-apps

You'll get your first custom application automatically. It will have some basic scopes for REST API requests, though you'll need to develop an endpoint to work with our Webhooks API.

Please note, this application won't do anything in your store by itself, but it will grant ability to work with the store through API. So you'll need to have your own backend for the integration.

Main applications settings are: scopes, endpoints (URLs), client_id and client_secret values (permanent), access_token/secret_token (permanent until the app is not reinstalled/deleted from the store).

Read more about application scopes and tokens here: https://api-docs.ecwid.com/reference/authentication-basics
And about Webhooks API here: https://api-docs.ecwid.com/reference/webhooks

Small note: you can't update application settings from the #develop-apps page, it works in read-only mode.

So, basically, your first 3 steps are:

1. Get a custom application for your store
2. Develop an endpoint, which can receive incoming POST requests (webhooks)
3. Send us your application name or client_id, your URL for webhooks and webhook events you'd like to receive, additional scopes you need

We will update your application, so you can start working with REST API requests and receiveng webhooks from the store.

Comment: Please take a look at [answer] and improve your answer. Stack Overflow is not a help desk.